# HttpPost not working in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

When I use the following code in Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images"), 
                               Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
    file.SaveAs(path);

    ViewBag.Message = "File Uploaded Successfully";

    return View();
}
```

When I Run the Application I got the Following error

```
---Server Error in '/' Application.
---The resource cannot be found.
```

When I remove `[HttpPost]` it loads but file not uploaded...

Can any one help me?.......

Comment: Can you update your question with the code/form which you use to call the action from your view?

Comment: Is there another `Index` method in your controller has the attribute `[HttpGet]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are creating the form like below,

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", 
        FormMethod.Post,                
        new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```